# How Can I import Multibit Private Key into Electrum or Blockchain.com

Tags: private-key, multibit

I am having trouble importing a multibit private key into electrum and blockchaing.com.  The key is declared invalid.

the key looks like this

U2FsdGVkX1+vNknxxxxxxxxxxxxxxU/KiWdlFKlBCv0y613C+rP2t3JMGnuR2xxxxxxxxk/gNe9S
lvv/OJQGbRJ4qP07m3CII4FLvovMg71F8cXSav15QeIxxxxxxxxf

Is this the entire key?
Or
Do I extract segments from the key above? What segment?

Answer (score 0):

> **I am having trouble importing a multibit private key into electrum and blockchain.com.**

The presence of '/' and '+' indicate that your key is encoded in [Base64](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64)

It is likely that the wallets you mention need the key to be presented in [Wallet Import Format (WIF)](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Wallet_import_format)

For example, [Importing your private keys into Electrum](https://bitcoinelectrum.com/importing-your-private-keys-into-electrum/) says

> Electrum supports mini private keys and full sized keys in Wallet Import Format (WIF).

also [How to import keys to Blockchain.info?](https://allprivatekeys.com/how-to-import-private-keys) says

> You can enter WIF (Wallet Import/Export Format) or compressed private key.

---

I would decode the Base64 into Hexadecimal and then follow the procedure described for WIF.

---

Related question

- [Correct way to convert a 256-bit private key to WIF?](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/44283/13866)

---

Ian Coleman's "Bitcoin Key Compression Tool" can be downloaded and run offline and might be useful. Obviously you need to be very careful choosing and using software that will be given your private key.

---

> **Is this the entire key? Or Do I extract segments from the key above? What segment?**

I think that looks too long to be a 256-bit number. However, since I am not familiar with Multibit I wouldn't know what to expect and can't identify it. After running it through Base64 decoding, things might be clearer to you?

Answer (score 0):

Basicaly, I think that `U2FsdGVkX1+vNknxxxxxxxxxxxxxxU/KiWdlFKlBCv0y613C+rP2t3JMGnuR2xxxxxxxxk/gNe9S lvv/OJQGbRJ4qP07m3CII4FLvovMg71F8cXSav15QeIxxxxxxxxf` is an encrypted version of your private keys.

Your options are to use either MultiBit Classic or OpenSSL to decrypt the file.

I saw a topic about it which is interesting, have a look [here](https://bitcointalk.org/index.php?topic=3366511.0).